# What is wrong with this? Either the filtering or the variables in the sql query

Tags: php, sql

can someone enlight me and show me where my mistake is?

```
if (isset($_POST["name"], $_POST["value"], $_POST["pk"])) {

    $name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $_POST["name"]);
    $value = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $_POST["value"]);
    $pk = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $_POST["pk"]);

    if ($name === "char_name" || $name === "char_geschlecht" || $name === "char_rasse") {
        include_once 'mysqli.php';
        $verbindung->query("UPDATE `charakter` SET `{$name}` = '{$value}' WHERE `char_id` = '{$pk}'");
    } else {
        include_once 'mysqli.php';
        $verbindung->query("UPDATE `geldbeutel` SET `{$name}` = '{$value}' WHERE `geldbeutel_id` = '{$pk}'");
    }

}
```

I get no error so I can't debug it correctly. My problem is that the post data is being sent but the query won't execute it correctly. If I replace the variable names with `$_POST["..."]` in the query it works.

Comment: Why do you think there is a mistake? What doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: The querry won't execute. The data is being sent and if I replace the $name parts with $_POST["name"] the query works and the database changes are done. Sadly I get no error so I can't debug it correctly.

Comment: My friend, Stackoverflow is not for "guys please verify my code". NO! Don't do that. You need to put your code, write details about the code, show the error returned, etc. So... rewrite your question please.

Comment: What if you just say `SET $name` instead of "SET `{$name}`"

Comment: @PatrickMaciel: I get no error, otherwise I could fix it easily. What should I write more about this question? I don't know what could be also helpful.

Comment: @CodeShark write the source (the form, the target file (of the form)), the result of the code in browser, the error, the apache `error.log`. (if you get not error, maybe it's because your `display_error = Off` in `php.ini`, or not?)

Comment: The source of the data is a table which gets edited with the help of javascript (x-editable for jquery). Then the data is send via POST to the index.php file (there is the if-clause too). Apache2 logs show no error - the same for MySQL. Error-logging is enabled and set to a high level.

Comment: Change your code so the query string is written into a variable which you echo before execution. This should make debugging easier for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why it didn't work. The code is fine but the variable `$name` contains the columns names which have an underscore in my database structure and I forgot to allow the underscore in the `preg_replace`.